# CSS3 Border-Radius with one border colored differently is bleeding its color

Tags: border, css

I have a fluid-width div with rounded corners using the border-radius, as well as a large border on one-side of the div colored differently.

When the browser window is small enough, the borders all behave as it should. However, when I enlarge the window size, I start to see the color bleed through in the center of my div.

I was wondering if anyone had an idea of a possible solution could be.

---

*The div has two classes:*

> **.info-box** {border: 1px solid #CCC; margin-bottom: 15px;
>   -moz-border-radius: 6px;
>   -webkit-border-radius: 6px; border-radius: 6px; background: #F3F3F3;}
>
> **.seller-msg** {border-left: 7px solid #EF831B;}

---

*It seems like the height of the div is also affecting it as well somehow.*

Screenshot

[image]

Comment: "the browser window" What browser?

Comment: Hmm do you observe this in any other browsers?

Comment: Just tested it, and it appears to happen only in Webkit =(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crikey, looks like you’ve found a WebKit bug. Nasty one.

The best I can come up with for a workaround is to add an extra `<div>` (whee, it’s like IE6 all over again) inside `.seller-msg`, and put the thin grey border on that `<div>` instead.

- http://jsfiddle.net/9a3Gp/3/

Hopefully someone can come up with something better.

---

If you wanted to report the bug to the WebKit team, the procedure is detailed here:

- http://www.webkit.org/quality/reporting.html

I’ve [downloaded the latest nightly build](http://nightly.webkit.org/) (r106067 on Mac OS X at time of writing), and the bug is present there too:

- http://jsfiddle.net/9a3Gp/

I’ve also done a Bugzilla search for “border-radius color”, and I can’t see any bugs that match this one.

- https://bugs.webkit.org/buglist.cgi?query_format=specific&order=relevance+desc&bug_status=__open__&product=WebKit&content=border-radius+color

Comment: Thanks for your help, and yeah I thought about the extra <div>, but seemed like there should be a better solution.

Comment: Sure, maybe someone else will come up with one.