# Space between rounded border and element

Tags: html, css

I've encountered a small visual problem. A parent with a rounded border will place a small space between parent and child. Both firefox and chrome.

What could be the cause of this?

[image: Circlewborder]

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Alex_Gr/5nev98h6/1/)**

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent {
    border: 10px solid #aaa;
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
}
.child {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #aaa;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9024220/css3-border-radius-with-one-border-colored-differently-is-bleeding-its-color

Comment: ...and this SO search http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=border%20radius%20bleed

Comment: [Workaround](http://jsfiddle.net/5nev98h6/3/)

Comment: @suslov Unfortunally the background-color has to be white